# Kubernetes: kubectl apply does not update pods when using "latest" tag

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm using `kubectl apply` to update my Kubernetes pods:

```
kubectl apply -f /my-app/service.yaml
kubectl apply -f /my-app/deployment.yaml
```

Below is my service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    run: my-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    run: my-app 
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    nodePort: 30769
```

Below is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: dockerhubaccount/my-app-img:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-app-img-credentials
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
```

This works fine the first time, but on subsequent runs, my pods are not getting updated.

I have read the suggested workaround at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33664 which is:

```
kubectl patch deployment my-app -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

I was able to run the above command, but it did not resolve the issue for me.

I know that I can trigger pod updates by manually changing the image tag from "latest" to another tag, but I want to make sure I get the latest image without having to check Docker Hub.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As per the same issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33664#issuecomment-497242094, with Kubernetes 1.15 command `kubectl rollout restart` can be used to restart resource

Comment: Indeed. You need: `kubectl rollout restart deploy <name>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood the workaround command I gave from the link.

I thought it was a one-time command that configured my deployment to treat all future `kubectl apply` commands as a trigger to update my pods.

I actually just had to run the command every time I wanted to update my pods:

```
kubectl patch deployment my-app -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"
```

Many thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 18):

If nothing changes in the deployment spec, the pods will not be updated for you. This is one of many reasons it is not recommended to use `:latest`, as the other answer went into more detail on. The `Deployment` controller is very simple and pretty much just does `DeepEquals(old.Spec.Template, new.Spec.Template)`, so you need some actual change, such as you have with the PATCH call by setting a label with the current datetime.

Comment: kubectl patch deployment <your_deployment_name> -n <your_namespace_name> -p '{"spec":{"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt":"'"$(date +%s)"'"}}}}}'

Answer (score 12):

You're missing an [`imagePullPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) in your deployment. Try this:

```
containers:
- name: my-app
  image: dockerhubaccount/my-app-img:latest
  imagePullPolicy: Always
```

The default policy is `ifNotPresent` which is why yours is not updating.

I will incorporate two notes from the link:

> **Note:** You should avoid using the **`:latest`** tag when deploying containers in production as it is harder to track which version of the image is running and more difficult to roll back properly

> **Note:** The caching semantics of the underlying image provider make even `imagePullPolicy: Always` efficient. With Docker, for example, if the image already exists, the pull attempt is fast because all image layers are cached and no image download is needed

Comment: According to kubernetes official documentation, you can omit the imagePullPolicy and use :latest as the tag for the image. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images

Comment: @PrafullLadha According to the same documentation using `latest` is discouraged, and the default policy is `ifNotPresent`. Please see the update on my answer. In fact the very first sentence on your link is the answer I gave above

Comment: `IfNotPresent` is not the default when the tag is `latest`. It's not recommended you use that feature, but it is present to reduce unexpected behavior.

Comment: I see, fair enough, was not aware of that

Comment: @rath Thanks, I tried adding "imagePullPolicy: Always" to my deployment.yaml, but it did not work.
I seem to have misunderstood the workaround command from the link I gave.
It was not a one-time command that made future kubectl apply commands update pods, it was the actual command that updated the pods.
So all I had to do was run the command whenever I wanted to update my pods.
Will add this as an answer later.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things here that relates the issue,

1. It is suggested to use `kubectl apply` for the first time while creating a resource and later recommended to use `kubectl replace` or `kubectl edit` or `kubectl patch` commands which subsequently call the `kubectl apply`.
2. Once you create a service using either `kubectl apply` or `kubetcl create` you cannot replace that service with a yaml file. In other words, service generates a **random IP** that **cannot** be **patched or replaced**. The only option to recreate a service is to delete the service and recreate it with the same name.

> **NOTE:** When I tried replacing a service using `kubectl apply` command while I was trying to create a backup and restore solution
>   resulted this below error.

```
kubectl apply -f replace-service.yaml -n restore-proj
The Service "test-q12" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "10.102.x.x": provided IP is already allocated.
```

Comment: Ah, I see, yes, doing `delete` and `create` is perfectly fine instead of `apply`. You can use an Ingress to make the service accessible in a better way

Comment: @rath You can always use a ingress or if you are on any cloud provider you can use auto provisioned load balancer by service to route traffic to the Pods in round robin.

Comment: One quick question, is kubectl apply idempotent ? or we should use it only once.