# Set command doesn't work for the deployment update in Azure Kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I'm using Azure DevOps pipelines to update our deployment in K8s cluster in Azure. It used to be working fine until yesterday, as for some reason the Pods in the cluster remain in their previous state. I can see that the image was successfully updated in ACR (container registry) and has a label 'latest'. However, the release pipeline doesn't seem to be doing anything useful. I use 'set' command in the task to update the Pod (it is well described in the Kubernetes docs and cheatsheet [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/))

This is the command sample extracted from the log:
`kubectl set image deployments/identityserver identityserver='myacr'/identityserver:latest -n identityserver-dev`

As it indicates, I'm getting the latest image from ACR and trying to roll an update. It executes well (both in cmd and Azure DevOps). no errors, although, the Pod remains unaffected. Have I missed something in the docs? Should I raise the ticket with Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

why do you have `'` in image name? also, `latest` wont work if you already have `latest` on the image, you need to be specific https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33664.

This is not an Azure issue

Comment: It's not an image name. It supposed to be a container registry name. I just removed it replacing with 'myacr', sorry if it's misleading. Concerning the 'latest' didn't quite get how it was working before then?

Comment: you need to modify something in the deployment manifest to trigger redeployment, say annotation, or label, else it wont work and was never working

Comment: Hmm, this partially answers why it was working before, as I was updating the manifest along with the code... Although, it doesn't sound right, does it? )

Comment: not sure what doesnt sound right :) this is a known kubernetes "feature". I've told you how to work around this behavior, can you confirm its working now?

Comment: well, deleting the Pod has helped, although, it doesn't look like an automation

Comment: yeah, deleting the pod will trigger redeployment. once again, you need to use specific image tag (like 1.0.1), not latest. and update it to new image tag (1.0.3).

Answer (score 1):

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591417/kubernetes-kubectl-apply-does-not-update-pods-when-using-latest-tag) answers to similar question on SO, on why it is not a good option to use `:latest` tag in your Deployment spec, along with workarounds provided.