# In docker, what does it mean to "reduce the cache interval of the build-index component"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, uber-kraken

We are using [Uber Kraken](https://github.com/uber/kraken) to increase container download speeds in a kubernetes cluster, it works great.

However, we commonly mutate tags (upload a new version of `:latest`). In the [limitations section of the Uber Kraken Github page](https://github.com/uber/kraken#limitations) they state:

> Mutating tags (e.g. updating a latest tag) is allowed, however, a few things will not work: tag lookups immediately afterwards will still return the old value due to Nginx caching, and replication probably won't trigger. We are working on supporting this functionality better. If you need tag mutation support right now, please **reduce the cache interval of the build-index component**. If you also need replication in a multi-cluster setup, please consider setting up another Docker registry as Kraken's backend.

What do they mean by *"reduce the cache interval of the build-index component"*? I don't quite understand what they are referring to in the docker universe.

Comment: Can you configure your CI system to have a unique tag per build?  There are a lot of practical problems using `:latest` in Kubernetes (the easiest example is [kubectl apply does not update pods when using “latest” tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591417/kubernetes-kubectl-apply-does-not-update-pods-when-using-latest-tag); it will also make it impossible to roll back a deployment, and can lead to inconsistent results when different `latest` images are on different nodes) and I wouldn't try to work around this if fixing the tagging strategy was an option.

Comment: We're deploying batch jobs and we typically bake our latest source files into the image with a build/push step before submitting the kubernetes job. The alternate option is to git commit and git pull in the container, but that creates a large number of git commits and hassle that's much more conveniently handled with a few 100kb container-layer update each time we submit. An option is to version our tags `:v1, :v2, ..., :vn`, but that means constantly cleaning up the registry, more annoying maintenance. There were no issues (other than undue load on the registry) prior to using the Kraken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence comes from [PR 61](https://github.com/uber/kraken/pull/61/files).

It offers a better alternative than the previous documentation, which stated:

> Mutating tags is allowed, however the behavior is undefined.
> A few things will go wrong:
>
> - replication probably won't trigger, and
> - most tag lookups will probably still return the old tag due to caching.
>
> We are working supporting this functionality better.
> If you need mutation (e.g. updating a latest tag) right now, please consider implementing your own index component on top of a consistent key-value store.

That last sentence was before:

> please consider setting up another docker registry as Kraken's backend,
> and reduce cache interval of build-index component

That would replace the current [Storage Backend For Origin And Build-Index](https://github.com/uber/kraken/blob/59fa7bcab998ca1abb7a2c268017db240cb0835e/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#configuring-storage-backend-for-origin-and-build-index).

Comment: Ah, so the cache interval of the build-index is a configuration of the registry itself, e.g. not something I can change on hub.docker.com, only if I use a registry which I control. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what they meant.